# Validate if random IPs stored in a table belong to a set of subnets stored in another table

Tags: sql, presto

I have two tables named `stored_ips` and `ip_subnets`. The first contains a column named `ip` with random IPs, and the second one, contains a column named `ip_cidr` that contains ip subnets with the following format `'127.0.0.0/16'`. With a `presto query`, I want to obtain which random IPs are part of the stored IP CIDR.

I've been trying to use Presto subqueries or left joins with the `is_subnet_of()` function with no success.

Subquery example:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  stored_ips
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      ip_subnets
    WHERE
      IS_SUBNET_OF(
        IPPREFIX(ip_subnets.ip_cidr),
        IPADDRESS(stored_ips.ip)
      )
  )
```

Left Join example:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  stored_ips
  LEFT JOIN ip_subnets AS is ON IS_SUBNET_OF(
    IPPREFIX (ip_subnets.ip_cidr),
    CAST(stored_ips.ip as IPADDRESS)
  )
```

But when I use static values the query works, for example:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  stored_ips
WHERE
  IS_SUBNET_OF(
        IPPREFIX('127.0.0.0/16'),
        IPADDRESS(stored_ips.ip)
      )
```

The idea is to avoid the subnet hardcoding.

Any ideas or tips? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve it with the following solution:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  stored_ips
  CROSS JOIN ip_subnets AS is
WHERE
  IS_SUBNET_OF(
      CAST(ip_subnets.ip_cidr as IPADDRESS),
      CAST(stored_ips.ip as IPADDRESS)
    )
```